# Quarkus: how to override a camelcase property with an environment variable?

Tags: java, properties, quarkus, microprofile

I am configuring Cloud SQL jdbc connection in which properties are defined with camel case:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.cloudSqlInstance=my-cloud-instance
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory
```

I need to set these properties via environment variables for production profile (so that they don't apply to other profiles).
I tried this:

```
QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_ADDITIONAL_JDBC_PROPERTIES_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
```

and this:

```
QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_ADDITIONAL_JDBC_PROPERTIES_cloudSqlInstance
```

Both didn't work.

**Question:** How to override a camelcase property with an environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use: `QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_ADDITIONAL_JDBC_PROPERTIES_CLOUDSQLINSTANCE`